# ForceFeedback with SlimDX?

Tags: slimdx

I havent found any articles or tutorials, is it possible?
It tried to invoke a Effect class but all I get is

E_INVALIDARG: An invalid parameter was passed to the returning function (-2147024809)

The code

```
[TestClass]
public class ForceFeedbackTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        using (var form = new Form())
        {
            var directInput = new DirectInput();

            foreach (var device in directInput.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameController, DeviceEnumerationFlags.AttachedOnly))
            {
                var controller = new Joystick(directInput, device.InstanceGuid);
                controller.SetCooperativeLevel(form.Handle, CooperativeLevel.Exclusive | CooperativeLevel.Background);
                controller.Acquire();

                int xAxisOffset = 0, yAxisOffset = 0;
                int nextOffset = 0;
                foreach (DeviceObjectInstance d in controller.GetObjects())
                {
                    if ((d.ObjectType & ObjectDeviceType.ForceFeedbackActuator)
                        != 0)
                    {
                        if (nextOffset == 0)
                            xAxisOffset = d.Offset;
                        else
                            yAxisOffset = d.Offset;
                        nextOffset++;
                    }
                }

                int[] offsets = new int[2];
                offsets[0] = xAxisOffset;
                offsets[1] = yAxisOffset;
                int[] coords = { 0, 0 };

                var info = controller.GetEffects(EffectType.All).First();

                var args = new EffectParameters();
                args.Flags = EffectFlags.ObjectOffsets | EffectFlags.Cartesian;
                var typeSpec = new ConstantForce();


                args.Duration = 1000;
                args.SamplePeriod = controller.Capabilities.ForceFeedbackSamplePeriod;
                args.Parameters = typeSpec;


                args.Gain = 5000;

                args.SetAxes(offsets, coords);

                args.StartDelay = 500;

                var effect = new Effect(controller, info.Guid);
                effect.SetParameters(args); //This is the line i get the error on.
                effect.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the offsets that you get from the `DeviceObjectInstance` for `SetAxes`. The MSDN mentions this, but it's somewhat sketchy:

> Offset in the native data format of the device. The native data format corresponds to the raw device data. The dwOfs member does not correspond to the device constant, such as DIJOFS_BUTTON0, for this object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.dideviceobjectinstance(v=vs.85).aspx

You can use `EffectFlags.ObjectIds` instead of `EffectFlags.ObjectOffsets` and pass in the `ObjectType` from the `DeviceObjectInstance`, to identify the axes.

As far as I remember, you can also use one of the static members of `JoystickObjects` class as the offsets for `SetAxes`, if you know which axes have an actuator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Xbox 360 controller or any controller that supports XInput I would use that instead of DirectInput. It is easier to use IMO and the forcefeed back is trival. Check out SlimDX.XInput. Most newer gamepads of the last few years support XInput.

VB.net code:

```
Dim player As Integer = 1 'Player can be 1-4
Dim gamePad As SlimDX.XInput.Controller = New SlimDX.XInput.Controller(player)

Public Sub VibrateController(ByVal rSpeed As Short, ByVal lSpeed As Short)
   Dim vibSettings As New SlimDX.XInput.Vibration()
   vibSettings.LeftMotorSpeed = lSpeed
   vibSettings.RightMotorSpeed = rSpeed
   gamePad.SetVibration(vibSettings)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for using it like me, i found working example in https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/blob/main/DirectInput/FFConst/ffconst.cpp

thats how i made it work in c#:

```
var directInput = new DirectInput();
JoystickState joys = new JoystickState();
var joy = new Joystick(directInput, dev.InstanceGuid);
joy.SetCooperativeLevel(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, CooperativeLevel.Exclusive | CooperativeLevel.Background);
joy.Acquire();
joy.GetCurrentState(ref joys);
joy.Properties.SetRange(0, short.MaxValue);

int[] offsets = { 0 };
int[] coords = { 0 };
var info = joy.GetEffects(EffectType.ConstantForce).First();

var args = new EffectParameters();
args.Flags = EffectFlags.Cartesian | EffectFlags.ObjectOffsets;
args.Duration = -1;
args.SamplePeriod = 0;
args.Gain = 10000;
args.TriggerButton = -1;
args.TriggerRepeatInterval = 0;
args.Envelope = null;
args.SetAxes(offsets, coords);

var typeSpec = new ConstantForce();
typeSpec.Magnitude = 0;
args.Parameters = typeSpec;


var effect = new Effect(joy, info.Guid, args);
effect.Start(1, EffectPlayFlags.None);


while (true)
{
    var mouse = Cursor.Position;
    var x = mouse.X - 2560 / 2;
    args.Parameters = new ConstantForce() { Magnitude = x * 10 };
    effect.SetParameters(args, EffectParameterFlags.Start | EffectParameterFlags.TypeSpecificParameters | EffectParameterFlags.Direction);
    effect.Start(1, EffectPlayFlags.None);

    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```